# Copying date to next cell in new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Struggle with this code below.

What I am trying to achieve is I have a purchase order form which when one is generated I would like to be able to copy certain cells to a purchase order log on a different sheet.

Currently I have this code

```
Sub Range_PasteSpecial_Values1()

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Which works but it does copy these cells into the row below in my purchase orders log.

Hope this is clear and thanks for your help

```
Public Sub CopyRows() 
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select 
    ' Find the last row of data 
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
    ' Loop through each row 
    For x = 2 To FinalRow 
        ' Decide if to copy based on column D 
        ThisValue = Cells(x, 4).Value 
        If ThisValue = "A" Then 
            Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 33).Copy 
            Sheets("SheetA").Select 
            NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 
            Cells(NextRow, 1).Select 
            ActiveSheet.Paste 
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select 
        ElseIf ThisValue = "B" Then 
            Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 33).Copy 
            Sheets("SheetB").Select 
            NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 
            Cells(NextRow, 1).Select 
            ActiveSheet.Paste 
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select 
        End If 
    Next x 
End Sub
```

Comment: your post is not clear, what are you trying to achieve ? can you post a screen-shot of the before and after ?

Comment: You should try to [avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)